# React-Native - Reload app automatically when fetched JSON is updated

Tags: ios, react-native, refresh, page-refresh

I'm fetching a JSON on my RN app that is returning a boolean true/false to determine whether the content is meant to be rendered or not.

It's globally working fine, just one issue: when the boolean is updated from false to true my app does not load the new content unless I hard-quit the app and re-open it.

What method would you guys recommend to refresh the app whenever the JSON is modified?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Function which you want to call every time, put it inside componentDidMount() .It will get called on page reload. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx mate. What if I want the page to be updated without leaving it?

Comment: use setState() metod and put ur changing data in it.

Comment: Could you dumb it down a bit? I'm this huge RN rookie :-/

Comment: do u have idea about state and prop in RN ?Please read about it then it'll be  bit easier to understand setState() method. Please revert if any doubt.

Comment: Thx @omkar. Yes I do have idea about state and prop. I re-read the documentation anyway to make sure I wasn't missing something; Turns out my problem wasn't state related. It seems that in my case the fetch API is returning old data when being rendered. It takes a setInterval to make the fetch API update the data.